# Clear rich text box and leave certain strings

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have lots of data in my rich text box, what I am trying to do is clear it and only leave words that begin with AZ, is this possible at all?  I have tried the following coding but it fails with

```
String cannot be of zero length.
Parameter name: oldValue
```

The code is

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim str As String
        str = rtbjw.Text
        If Not str.Contains("AZ") = True Then
            rtbjw.Text = rtbjw.Text.Replace("", "").Trim()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Example text

```
AZ0034   14         AZ0034L1    ART3    LTD   0 srv01   000_00000_LTD   ECR   0  - BE   Active    -
AZ0003   10         AZ0003L1    ART3    LTD   0 srv01   000_00000_LTD   ECR   8  - BE   Active    -
AZ0008    9         AZ0008L1    ART3    LTD   0 srv01   000_00000_LTD   ECR  12  - BE   Active    -
AZ0010    8         AZ0010L1    ART3    LTD   0 srv01   000_00000_LTD   ECR   7  - BE   Active    -
AZ0009    7         AZ0009L1    ART3    LTD   0 srv01   000_00000_LTD   ECR   7  - BE   Active    -
AZ0004    2         AZ0004L1    ART3    LTD   0 srv01   000_00000_LTD   ECR   3  - BE   Active    -
AZ0006    1         AZ0006L1    ART3    NONE      - -   --- ECR   7  - BE   Active    -
AZ0007    -         AZ0007L1    ART3    NONE      - -   JO  ECR   8  - BE   Active    -
```

Comment: I can't seem to follow the code. You are assigning the value of rich text box to str. If str contains "AZ" then you are trying to replace empty zero length value "" with empty zero length value "" and then trim... makes no sense. I would think you need to look for words in str and then loop through each word. If the word does not begin with AZ then delete the word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rtbjw.Text = rtbjw.Text.Replace("", "").Trim()`

will only replace empty strings found within `rtjbw.Text` with empty strings. I'm sure you noticed that it didn't actually do anything, because there aren't any empty strings to replace. At any rate, if you want to only leave words that begin in "AZ" then this is not the right approach. Few different methods, including RegEx would work. However, I'm not familiar with RegEx enough to provide a solution using it, but this will work just as well.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim strArr() As String = rtbjw.Text.Split(" ")
    rtbjw.Clear()
    For Each item In strArr
        If item.StartsWith("AZ") Then
            If rtbjw.Text.Length > 0 Then rtbjw.Text &= " "
            rtbjw.Text &= item
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

What I did here was take the contents of `rtbjw` and assign it to a string array, splitting it by a space. This creates a list of "words" (assuming that each word really is separated by a space). Since we now have a list of all the "words" in the textbox, the textbox is cleared of all text.

Then, in the for loop, I'm looking at each item in the list of words, and if it begins with "AZ" (using the `StartsWith()` method), I'm doing two things. First, if the length of the text in the textbox is greater than 0, I add a space to what's in the textbox currently (to separate the words, and the greater than 0 check is to prevent adding a space as the very first character), then adding the word which begins with "AZ" to the end of the text in the textbox.

EDIT: Because I was curious and I'm learning how to use them, I also modified this to use a LINQ query instead. Does basically the same thing, but instead of assigning the text to a string array, the text is stored in the queryResult variable. See the following.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim queryResults As IEnumerable = From word In rtbjw.Text.Split(" ")
                                      Where word.StartsWith("AZ")
    rtbjw.Clear()
    For Each word In queryResults
        If rtbjw.TextLength > 0 Then rtbjw.Text &= " "
        rtbjw.Text &= word
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your help and explanation, that will help me immensely.  The only strange thing is that it doesnt seem to pick up all the words in teh For loop? for example in the text in the rtb there are atleast 10 different words that begin with AZ however it seems to only show the first word that begins with AZ so AZ0052 and not AZ0025 AZ0059 AZ0080 and so on.

Comment: The code is going off the assumption that each word is separated by a space. It worked for me when I used the text "AZThis is a AZtest to see AZif AZit's working." which left the text "AZThis AZtest AZif AZit's" in the textbox. Perhaps you could post the data which is actually being filtered?

Comment: I will add an example text to the original post at the top, do you think the issue is each field is seperated by tab rather than space? I know using the above assumption it will also include the same words as it has L1 at the end but that code i will look at later.

Comment: hi rian, thanks for your help i think i got it sorted now, the problem was it was using tabs rather than space so using rtbjw.Text.Split(vbTab) fixed it :)

Comment: exactly the change I would have made. glad I could help!